# Is it possible to hide certain files from "show package contents"?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I have a MacOS app coded in swift, and when someone right clicks > show package contents there is a file that reveals some information I do not want the user to see. Is it at all possible to hide that file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to secure data on the client (mac) side. If your program can read something, so can a hacker. You can do 3 things about it:

1. Make it obfuscated enough to make it annoying to deal with, hoping that bad actors would get discouraged.
2. Make the reward of reading the sensitive data lower, so there's less incentive to do so
3. Make the sensitive data be black boxed by a server you control and have secured, and have all the sensitive operations be out-sourced to computation on that secure server.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't hide files in a meaningful way.

If you name the file starting with a dot (".") they are not shown in the Finder by default, but that's very easy to get around.

Better to encrypt the file and decrypt it in your app. That way nosy users can see the file but can't make any sense out of the contents.

Comment: But where would you store the key?

Comment: That's a classic security problem. If you program can decrypt it, so can hackers.

Comment: Yep, that's what I was alluding to.

Comment: @DuncanC For example, this [GitHub thread on trying to get Sketch free](https://gist.github.com/Bhavdip/76c581d7ac03bdce6d226a2e8c522df4) involves showing packaged contents and viewing hidden files.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Its a .plist file i'm not really sure on how to go about encrypting it but I guess I have some research to do.